# Meteor Galaxy Deployment - Console errors while Hosting and no Routes are shown

Tags: jquery, node.js, meteor, deployment, routes

As described above,I have a problem which shows up while the my app is hosted on Galaxy. I am not able to see any content of my site:

I only see this:
[image: My app says, that no routes are defined]

But I defined all routes by using iron router. I have some react-router things in my import folder, maybe this is the issue? I don´t know...

Additionally I receive these error messages:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://myapp.eu.meteorapp.com/' was
>   loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet
>   'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700'.
>   This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

and

> Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1
>   or higher, but lower than version 3
>       at 21478a3d30e8f0ae766afe74c96bb1f3590793e6.js:115
>       at 21478a3d30e8f0ae766afe74c96bb1f3590793e6.js:115
>       at 21478a3d30e8f0ae766afe74c96bb1f3590793e6.js:115
>       at 21478a3d30e8f0ae766afe74c96bb1f3590793e6.js:115

I am using the Chrome browser. I just want to see anything...please

**UPDATE**

All of my routes look like this:

```
Router.route('/', function () {
    Router.go('home');
});

Router.route('/imprint', function () {
    this.render('imprint');
});

Router.route('/dashboard', function () {
    this.render('dashboard');
});
```

and sometimes like:

```
Router.route('/do/:home/editDetails/:Id', function () {
  var params = this.params;
  Session.set('home', params.home);
  Session.set('Id', params.Id);
  this.render('editDetails');
});
```

or equivalent. I am using the meteor iron router package. Here is my complete packages-file:

```
meteor-base@1.1.0             # Packages every Meteor app needs to have
mongo@1.2.0                   # The database Meteor supports right now
blaze-html-templates    # Compile .html files into Meteor Blaze views
reactive-var@1.0.11            # Reactive variable for tracker
tracker@1.1.3                 # Meteor's client-side reactive programming library

standard-minifier-css@1.3.4   # CSS minifier run for production mode
standard-minifier-js@2.1.1    # JS minifier run for production mode
es5-shim@4.6.15                # ECMAScript 5 compatibility for older browsers
ecmascript@0.8.2              # Enable ECMAScript2015+ syntax in app code

kadira:blaze-layout     # Layout manager for blaze (works well with FlowRouter)
less@2.7.9                    # Leaner CSS language


practicalmeteor:mocha             # A package for writing and running your meteor app and package tests with mocha
johanbrook:publication-collector  # Test a Meteor publication by collecting its output


iron:router
zimme:iron-router-active
natestrauser:animate-css
kevohagan:sweetalert
chrismbeckett:toastr
fortawesome:fontawesome
session@1.1.7
logging@1.1.17
reload@1.1.11
random@1.0.10
ejson@1.0.14
spacebars
check@1.2.5
okgrow:router-autoscroll
joshdellay:meteor-ladda-bootstrap
d3js:d3
emdagon:c3js
andrasph:clockpicker
tsega:bootstrap3-datetimepicker

shell-server@0.2.4
http@1.2.12
peerlibrary:xml2js
meteorhacks:npm
json
jaredmartin:future

accounts-password@1.4.0
accounts-ui-unstyled@1.2.1
altapp:recaptcha
chart:chart
jackyqiu:meteor-jvectormap
jasny:bootstrap
meteorhacks:async
meteorhacks:ssr
mizzao:jquery-ui
mrgalaxy:stripe
mrt:footable

themeteorchef:bert
themeteorchef:jquery-validation
timmyg:wow
yagni:split-on-newlines
dynamic-import@0.1.1
alanning:roles
email@1.2.3
momentjs:moment
cosio55:autoform-cloudinary
aldeed:autoform
aldeed:collection2
nekojira:cloudinary-jquery-upload
allow-deny@1.0.6
cesarve:simple-chat
templating
ddp-rate-limiter

npm-container
mdg:validated-method
underscore
dburles:factory
practicalmeteor:chai
xolvio:cleaner
jquery
```

Due to the fact that I use a Boostrap-Theme, the meteor folder structure was given. Because I had issues with the deployment, I created a new meteor project with the `--full` flag and copied my code into it.

Everything is working on localhost.

```
I have an import folder, with some code like:

import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import App from '../../ui/layouts/App.js';
import Documents from '../../ui/pages/Documents.js';
import NewDocument from '../../ui/pages/NewDocument.js';
import EditDocument from '../../ui/containers/EditDocument.js';
import ViewDocument from '../../ui/containers/ViewDocument.js';
import Index from '../../ui/pages/Index.js';
import Login from '../../ui/pages/Login.js';
import NotFound from '../../ui/pages/NotFound.js';
import RecoverPassword from '../../ui/pages/RecoverPassword.js';
import ResetPassword from '../../ui/pages/ResetPassword.js';
import Signup from '../../ui/pages/Signup.js';

const authenticate = (nextState, replace) => {
  if (!Meteor.loggingIn() && !Meteor.userId()) {
    replace({
      pathname: '/login',
      state: { nextPathname: nextState.location.pathname },
    });
  }
};

Meteor.startup(() => {
  render(
    <Router history={ browserHistory }>
      <Route path="/" component={ App }>
        <IndexRoute name="index" component={ Index } />
        <Route name="documents" path="/documents" component={ Documents } onEnter={ authenticate } />
        <Route name="newDocument" path="/documents/new" component={ NewDocument } onEnter={ authenticate } />
        <Route name="editDocument" path="/documents/:_id/edit" component={ EditDocument } onEnter={ authenticate } />
        <Route name="viewDocument" path="/documents/:_id" component={ ViewDocument } onEnter={ authenticate } />
        <Route name="login" path="/login" component={ Login } />
        <Route name="recover-password" path="/recover-password" component={ RecoverPassword } />
        <Route name="reset-password" path="/reset-password/:token" component={ ResetPassword } />
        <Route name="signup" path="/signup" component={ Signup } />
        <Route path="*" component={ NotFound } />
      </Route>
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('react-root')
  );
});
```

Maybe this affects the routing? I also had automatically loaded the Flow-router package in my app, when I created the new --full project. I removed the package. However, I am using Blaze and iron-router. No react or Flow-router.

Many thanks

Comment: Well, show us your routes then. It's clearly that something isn't working.

Comment: The second error comes from meteor bootstrap package. I had the same issue and removed it and used the npm package via `meteor npm install bootstrap`

Comment: I made a big update section. @Jankapunkt, I did the same and the JQuery error message is gone now, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

I don´t know the exact error, but it wasn´t an issue about the routes themselves. I draw up a complete new project with my code and checked every file. The error must has to do something with the meteor package file and its dependencies in relation to npm. Everything is fine until I add all my needed packages. After I want to start the app, it fails and the console says that now npm is set up and I should restart the app. Than `npm-container` is in my package file and the "routes not found" thing occurs.

However, I used a previous version, deleted the packages and added my needed packages one by one and now it works. Thanks for your effort.